# Boot process in android devices

Tags: arm, soc

I was reading this informative blog post [here](http://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/Booting/linux-bootstrap-1.html) about the booting process on x64. In what ways is the booting process on ARM different? I had a look at Raspberry pi and it seems that the GPU is what executes before control is handed over to ARM processor. Are there any similar resources you have come across for ARM processors?

Answer (score 1):

Just like the x86 boot process is documented in documents available at intel.com arm boot process is documented at arm.com as is any other processor documented.

The full sized (non-cortex-m) arm cores start by executing at address zero for reset.  There is one instruction location for reset, one for data abort, undefined instruction, etc.  Similar to an interrupt vector table but instead of an address there is an instruction there ideally a branch.

processors historically have some non-volatile ram mapped into the boot space or vector table or whatever, then volatile ram if any elsewhere.  x86 historically near the top of ram, arm at the bottom.

ARM does not make chips like intel, it designs processor cores which other folks that make chips include in their chip designs instead of having to design their own cores and maintain compilers, etc.   So the chip vendor can solve the boot process in a number of ways, some have something non-volatile mapped low then after booting you can swap in ram to that address space, whatever.  In the case of the Raspberry Pi chips which are made by broadcom, they have their own gpu which actually boots the chip, it eventually reads a file assumed to be the linux kernel and root file system, but doesnt have to be.  It places that file in ram (by default) in the place where a linux kernel would be loaded by a bootloader like redboot or uboot, in this case by the gpu's arm loader.  the gpu then places a few breadcrumbs including the reset instruction(s) required to branch into the linux kernel (generally a very trivial thing), then release reset on the arm core allowing it to boot.  so basically the arm sees only ram which is kind of nice, but that is somewhat atypical for arm or other processors to do that.  Normally the main processor boots from non-volatile storage (eeprom, flash, etc) and then itself loads linux or whatever and branches to it.

A number of other processor types will have an interrupt vector table, including the arm cortex-m series which are thumb instruction set only cores.  they are designed to be microcontrollers and not carry as much overhead, so the first address slot is actually meant to be filled with the init value for the stack pointer, then the second is the address for reset, and then a zillion others.  The hardware is designed to preserve registers for you so that you can have the address to C functions right in the table and not have to have "some assembly required" wrappers written by you or the folks that ported the toolchain to this platform.   Other processor types will just have a vector table and some assembly is required to be wrapped around interrupts and such.

Comment: infocenter.arm.com and look at the arm architectural reference manual start with the oldest one as it is simpler, armv5 or armv6 whichever they named it.

Comment: for android devices specifically if you can figure out what the processor chip is, and then if that vendor provides information (allwinner and broadcom for example tend to only provide that to the actual customers that buy chips not users of the products) then you might find how and if other raspberry pi like two steps are used.  the ti omap chips for example do have docs available as I think do the marvell chips.